# Does the inode actually point to an address in the Disk?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, inode

How does the inode in the Linux File System actually point to a block on the disk? Does it contain a 64 bit addressable number that points from 0 to 2^63 - 1? Or is there a layer in between the inode structures and the actual disk addresses?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **it depends**.

Different file systems store inode information differently.  Some will store the actual file contents in the inode structure if the size is small enough, some will store virtual or actual block numbers as a 32 or 64 bit numbers or sometimes even another encoding, some will store an offset into the disk space, most will store more complex information to handle large files spanning many many blocks...

You can find the details for various file systems on the Internet, it is very interesting to understand file system performance.

Enjoy!

Comment: `...is the size is small enough` should be `...if the size is small enough`?

Answer (score 1):

As says in [osdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Ext2) for [ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) inodes :

> Like blocks, each inode has a numerical address. It is extremely important to note that unlike block addresses, inode addresses start at 1.
>
> Each inode contains 12 direct pointers, one singly indirect pointer, one doubly indirect block pointer, and one triply indirect pointer. The direct space "overflows" into the singly indirect space, which overflows into the doubly indirect space, which overflows into the triply indirect space.
>
> Direct Block Pointers: There are 12 direct block pointers. If valid, the value is non-zero. Each pointer is the block address of a block containing data for this inode.
>
> Singly Indirect Block Pointer: If a file needs more than 12 blocks, a separate block is allocated to store the block addresses of the remaining data blocks needed to store its contents. This separate block is called an indirect block because it adds an extra step (a level of indirection) between an inode and its data. The block addresses stored in the block are all 32-bit, and the capacity of stored addresses in this block is a function of the block size. The address of this indirect block is stored in the inode in the "Singly Indirect Block Pointer" field.
>
> Doubly Indirect Block Pointer: If a file has more blocks than can fit in the 12 direct pointers and the indirect block, a double indirect block is used. A double indirect block is an extension of the indirect block described above only now we have two intermediate blocks between the inode and data blocks. The inode structure has a "Doubly Indirect Block Pointer" field that points to this block if necessary.
>
> Triply Indirect Block Pointer: Lastly, if a file needs still more space, it can use a triple indirect block. Again, this is an extension of the double indirect block. So, a triple indirect block contains addresses of double indirect blocks, which contain addresses of single indirect blocks, which contain address of data blocks. The inode structure has a "Triply Indirect Block Pointer" field that points to this block if present.

[image: inode relations]

as you may know there is a logical inode in linux wich used in VFS.
The VFS inode data structure holds information about a file or directory on disk.

```
struct inode {
    kdev_t                       i_dev;
    unsigned long                i_ino;
    umode_t                      i_mode;
    nlink_t                      i_nlink;
    uid_t                        i_uid;
    gid_t                        i_gid;
    kdev_t                       i_rdev;
    off_t                        i_size;
    time_t                       i_atime;
    time_t                       i_mtime;
    time_t                       i_ctime;
    unsigned long                i_blksize;
    unsigned long                i_blocks;
    unsigned long                i_version;
    unsigned long                i_nrpages;
    struct semaphore             i_sem;
    struct inode_operations      *i_op;
    struct super_block           *i_sb;
    struct wait_queue            *i_wait;
    struct file_lock             *i_flock;
    struct vm_area_struct        *i_mmap;
    struct page                  *i_pages;
    struct dquot                 *i_dquot[MAXQUOTAS];
    struct inode                 *i_next, *i_prev;
    struct inode                 *i_hash_next, *i_hash_prev;
    struct inode                 *i_bound_to, *i_bound_by;
    struct inode                 *i_mount;
    unsigned short               i_count;
    unsigned short               i_flags;
    unsigned char                i_lock;
    unsigned char                i_dirt;
    unsigned char                i_pipe;
    unsigned char                i_sock;
    unsigned char                i_seek;
    unsigned char                i_update;
    unsigned short               i_writecount;
    union {
        struct pipe_inode_info   pipe_i;
        struct minix_inode_info  minix_i;
        struct ext_inode_info    ext_i;
        struct ext2_inode_info   ext2_i;
        struct hpfs_inode_info   hpfs_i;
        struct msdos_inode_info  msdos_i;
        struct umsdos_inode_info umsdos_i;
        struct iso_inode_info    isofs_i;
        struct nfs_inode_info    nfs_i;
        struct xiafs_inode_info  xiafs_i;
        struct sysv_inode_info   sysv_i;
        struct affs_inode_info   affs_i;
        struct ufs_inode_info    ufs_i;
        struct socket            socket_i;
        void                     *generic_ip;
    } u;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For ext4 fs, please 
Refer https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout

As per my understanding for ext4, Disk is divided into multiple blocks. Address stored in inode is basically block number. so, the actual address would be block_number*block_size.

"Generally, the block size will be 4KiB (the same size as pages on x86 and the block layer's default block size), though the actual size is calculated as 2 ^ (10 + sb.s_log_block_size) bytes"

Thanks